# Accessing local host to create a file from Putty (Linux)

Tags: linux, putty

Does anyone know how I can access my local host while puttying on to a linux vm?

So while on Putty I need to get access to the C: on my local computer and create a file using the touch command on my local PC.

Thanks

Comment: your question isn't clear. please [edit] your question, and rephrase your question.

Comment: Putty can be used as an [ssh client](https://digitz.org/old-blog/how-to-access-terminal-from-your/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not clear about what you want but as per my understanding you need to move to the Document `Root directory` of your `localhost`. And want to create files there.
To change/move to the desired directory in Linux you need `cd` command.
You can get detail by doing `man cd` in your putty terminal.
All you need is `cd /path/to/your/Document/root/` which is `/var/www/html` by default in every Linux machine(ofcourse after installing apache server).